# Безопасно подключиться к БД ModX из отдельного файла по cron

Tags: mysql, modx, cron, gd

ModX Revo
Формирую большую картинку из сотен маленьких, аватарки пользователей (для оптимизации времени загрузки страницы - грузится одна картинка весом 100кБ или 400 по 2кБ - есть некая разница)) )

Запрос банальный и без входящих параметров, т.е. `select img_id from table where val=20`, получаю выборку img_id (это unicid названия маленьких картинок).
Подключение к  БД стандартное для сниппета ModX через `$query = $modx->query($sql);`

Далее в цикле через GD-функции imagecreate, imagecopy, imagepng формирую одну картинку
По молодости сделал код генерации картинки в виде сниппета, сниппет вызываю  в шаблоне, шаблон соответственно привязан к определенной странице, страница вызывается через cron. Нашел опытным путем, что скрипт выполняется 15-20 сек, при этом запрос в БД 0,05сек, остальное работа PHP и наверное что-то добавляет сам ModX.
Попробовал оформить как отдельный файл php с подключением к БД как в старые добрые времена через указание паролей внутри файла, при этом вижу, что итоговый файл обновляется в течение секунды (тупо по времени изменения файла на фтп). **ModX, Карл?**
Как теперь поступить оптимальнее, чтобы, как говорится и рыбку съесть и на забор из кольев не попасть?))) Т.е. подключаться к БД без явного указания паролей в файле и в тоже время обойтись без причудливого API ModX. Запускать указанный код внутри сниппета видимо придется исключить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы подгрузить окружение *modX* достаточно выполнить:

```
require_once '/absolute/path/to/modx/config.core.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH.'model/modx/modx.class.php';
$modx = new modX();
```

И, дальше уже можете вызывать `$modx->query()`

См. https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/loading-modx-externally

Comment: по ссылке все три метода не запустились, сейчас ваш попробую. но в итоге-то АПИ все-таки грузится? мне по сути вообще нужна кастомная таблица, которая просто вставлена в БД движка, больше их ничто не связывает

Comment: @СергейВ. Вы правильно указываете путь в первом `require_once`? Ошибки какие-либо в логах есть?

Comment: @СергейВ. Сейчас "померял". Эти строчки выполняются примерно за 30мс и отъедают около 2.5 Мб памяти. Насколько это для вас критично? (и грузится далеко не все)

Comment: 30мс? это просто супер! буду долбить до упора, чтобы все-таки запустить, мне такая метода очень нравится! заодно и проверю, что же так грузит в моем варианте.... путь в первом require_once ставлю вроде бы правильно (4 уровень вложенности), так как крон говорит что выполнено успешно, может быть, тут еще зависит и от того, ГДЕ мой файл лежит? по идее не должно зависеть. кстати, где безопаснее такие файлы складывать, чтобы попусту никто не запускал их баловства ради? сейчас файл лежит в папке assets/components/mysupercomponent

Comment: @СергейВ Кстати строки я скопировал из указанной статьи, но на самом деле файл относительно корня modX __core/config/config.inc.php__. Убедитесь, что в первой строке указан абсолютный путь именно к нему